# How to redirect to a different page depending on user type in Django?

Tags: django

am unable to redirect to a different page depending on user type

***model.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

USER_CHOICES = (
    ('teacher', 'teacher',),
    ('student', 'student',),
)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    role = models.CharField(choices=USER_CHOICES, ...)

class Student(model.Models):
    role = models.OneToOneFieldField(CustomUser, ...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    admission_number = models.CharField(CustomUser, ...)


class Teacher(AbstractUser):
    role = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, ...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    teacher_number = models.CharField(unique=True, ...)
    

class Fees(model.Models):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, ...)
    paid = models.FloatField(...)
    balance = models.FloatField(...)
    total = models.FloatField(...)
```

The school admin should be able to create a teacher, student and update students school fees

***settings.py***
This is my reasoning, its vulnerable to errors

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'CustomUser'
```

***views.py***
took this from the answer below

```
login(request, user)
if user.role == 'student':
    return redirect('student_dashboard')
elif user.role == 'teacher':
    return redirect('teacher_dashboard')
... other cases ...
```

am stuck i dont know how to proceed on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `ChoiceField` in your `User` model like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ... your fields ...

    CHOICES = [
        ('student', 'student'),
        ('teacher', 'teacher'),
        ('parent', 'parent'),
        ... add more ...
    ]

    role = models.CharField(max_lenght=20, choices=CHOICES)
```

Then when loggin user in just use the simple `if` -> `elif` blocks to send your user to different pages, it will look something like this:

```
login(request, user)
if user.role == 'student':
    return redirect('student_dashboard')
elif user.role == 'teacher':
    return redirect('teacher_dashboard')
... other cases ...
```

Comment: Inheriting `AbstractBaseUser` is a bit overkill (also more complicated) for only adding choices `AbstractUser` would be more suitable.

Comment: it's just an example, the point is the `role` field :)

Comment: @Abdul  could you clarify something, should i use one app and create all my models in models.py or have different apps with respective models.py. I have used the `AbstractBaseUser` , does it come with extra fields, for example, the first_name am asking because if i try to query the first_name field i get the error does not exist

Comment: @miruni an app should have models that make sense to have together. For example if it's an ecommerce project one app could be product and one could be basket, etc. The `AbstractBaseUser` is a very basic version of the User model and leaves various field implementations to you, it's used when you want to customize things like username, etc.. If you only want to add some functionality on top of User you should override `AbstractUser` instead which has all the fields `User` has (in fact User simply inherits from `AbstractUser`).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat should be `choices=[...] or choices=(...)`